# How to speed up fmincon in MATLAB when there are many variables? Alternatives to MATLAB optimization toolbox?

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I need to solve an optimization problem with two nonlinear equality constraints. My function evaluation is very fast (less than a second) and I also provide fmincon with the gradients of my objective and constraint functions. However, when fmincon is slow when there are about 2000 variables, and it is very slow when there are 6000 variables. Considering my function evaluation is super fast, I guess the bottle neck is the speed of fmincon. How can I possibly speed up fmincon? If not, can anyone suggest any other optimization packages?

Comment: What is "slow"? How long does it take for 2000 variables?

Comment: It takes a few seconds for 2000 variables, and more than a minute for 6000 variables. As it normally takes a few thousand iterations, this means that it will take me a few hours for only one minimization. I have improved my function evaluation using parallel computing, but fmincon makes it impossible for me to solve a large number of minimizations...

Comment: fmincon is very general purpose.  Maybe you should figure out if which kind of problem you are solving and then a more specialized algorithm. There are plenty of packages out there.